# Not able to change text size of actionsheet button text

Tags: ios, font-size, uiactionsheet

Hi I am facing very different kind of problem. I am using actionsheet in my iPhone application. So when I use predefine values of `otherButtonTitles` and if I try to change the text size then it works fine. But when I add buttons dynamically then it's not working properly.

My code looks like this:

```
- (void)showActions
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
    otherButtonTitles:notifications, about, faq, settings, logout, nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    for (UIView *_currentView in actionSheet.subviews) {
    if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)_currentView;
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE_16];
    }
 }
}
```

So above thing working fine. But if I try following things its not working

```
-(void) showCategories
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:nil
    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // categoryData is string array....
    for (NSString *category in categoryData) {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:category];
    }
    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
 }
```

And I tried to change text size like above then its not working. Is there any reason? Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Copy/pasted your code and i found it working completely fine. Must be problem with your `category` array. Show us the contents of array.

Answer (score 0):

> When total number of buttons exceeds height to display without
>   scrolling this problem occurs. (If anyone else finds the way then
>   please post an answer. But i think there's no answer to this !!)

On 4 inch device (640x1136 resolution), number of max buttons displayed are **11**

On 3.5 inch device (640x960 resolution), number of max buttons displayed are **8**.

**A piece of advice:**: I think if you use actionsheet this way to display more than 10 elements, Apple could reject your app. Use [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) for this kind of behaviour.